# ASP.NET GridView/SPGridView automatically start edit mode

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I am looking for the best way to edit the following set of data within an ASP.NET GridView or SharePoint 2010 SPGridView.  I have a couple of Entity Framework classes (.NET 3.5 SP1!).  Lets say one is a parent and the other is a child.

I need to be able to show one of the parent fields, show a current value, and provide a textbox for a new value.  So essentially:

**Class1 Properties**

- string Name
- EntiityCollection Class2s

**Class2 Properties**

- DateTime EffectiveFrom
- double Value

**Grid Data Columns**

- Label Name (read only)
- Label Current Timestamp (read only)
- TextBox Current Value (read only)
- TextBox Current Timestamp
- TextBox Current Value

Current Timestamp and Current Value will need to be retrieved by essentially doing a select max on Current Timestamp for each Class1.

When a user enters the form, I need the GridView to present the fields for editing straight away.
when the user clicks on a save button, a new Class2 will be added to the Class1.Class2s for each row where the user has input some data.

Can this be done using a GridView?
Would it be better to dynamically create the fields per each record and style using CSS?
Any better ideas?